# Create new vertical json to horizontal in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON like below

```
 var data = [

        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 1590 },
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 },
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 2008 },
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 3900 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 1052 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 10122 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 1461 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 682 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 244 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 21 }

    ];
```

and i want to generate this JSON some thing like that

```
var firstYear = "2013";
    var secondYear = "2014";
    var thildYear = "2015";

    var sampleData = [
        { "week": 41, "firstYear": 1590, "secondYear": 1052, "thildYear": 682 },
        { "week": 42, "firstYear": 0, "secondYear": 0, "thildYear": 0 },
        { "week": 43, "firstYear": 2008, "secondYear": 10122, "thildYear": 244 },
        { "week": 44, "firstYear": 858, "secondYear": 1461, "thildYear": 21 }
    ];
```

i write a code but it does't work

```
  var jsonObjdata = [];
    var yearExist = "";
    var weekExist = "";
    var SampleRequestBody = {};
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        if (value.year != yearExist) {
            SampleRequestBody.week = value.week;
            SampleRequestBody.firstYear = value.changes;
            yearExist = value.year;
        }
        else if (value.year == yearExist && value.week == weekExist + 1) {
            SampleRequestBody.secondYear = value.changes;
        }
        else if (value.year == yearExist && value.week == weekExist + 1) {
            SampleRequestBody.thildYear = value.changes;
            jsonObjdata.push(SampleRequestBody);
        } 
    });
```

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another take at it using [array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var weeks = [], flatData;
flatData = data.reduce(function(outData, obj) {
    var tmp = {}, prop = 'year' + obj.year;
    if ((idx = weeks.indexOf(obj.week)) >= 0) {
        outData[idx][prop] = obj.changes;
    } else {
        weeks.push(obj.week);
        tmp['week'] = obj.week;
        tmp[prop] = obj.changes;
        outData.push(tmp);
    }
    return outData;
}, []);
```

It will return you an object array like this:

```
week    year2013    year2014    year2015
----    --------    --------    --------
41      1590        1052        682
42      0           0           0
43      2008        10122       244
44      3900        1461        21
```

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/kLg5f1wk/**
(*check console*)

**Demo Snippet:**
(*check console*)

```js
var data = [
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 1590 },
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 },
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 2008 },
        { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 3900 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 1052 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 10122 },
        { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 1461 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 682 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 244 },
        { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 21 }

], weeks = [], flatData;

flatData = data.reduce(function(outData, obj) {
    var tmp = {}, prop = 'year' + obj.year;
    if ((idx = weeks.indexOf(obj.week)) >= 0) {
        outData[idx][prop] = obj.changes;
    } else {
        weeks.push(obj.week);
        tmp['week'] = obj.week;
        tmp[prop] = obj.changes;
        outData.push(tmp);
    }
    return outData;
}, []);

console.table(flatData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of debugging your code I think a more "algorithmic" approach would be better. Consider this :

```
function processWeek(week) {
    var weekItem = { week: week };
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        if (item.week == week) switch (item.year) {
            case firstYear : weekItem.firstYear = item.changes; break;
            case secondYear : weekItem.secondYear = item.changes; break;
            case thildYear : weekItem.thildYear = item.changes; break;                
            default : alert('this will never happen'); break;    
        }
    })
    return weekItem;
}

for (var week=41;week<45;week++) {
    sampleData.push(processWeek(week));
}
```

The above produces the desired result -> **http://jsfiddle.net/by22q6h8/**

The idea is to narrow down the construct of new items to simple steps :

1. create the item
2. isolate weeks we are after
3. determine which `changes` go to which new attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for creating a temporary object and the later result array.

```js
var data = [{ "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 1590 }, { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 }, { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 2008 }, { "year": 2013, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 3900 }, { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 1052 }, { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 }, { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 10122 }, { "year": 2014, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 1461 }, { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 41, "changes": 682 }, { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 42, "changes": 0 }, { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 43, "changes": 244 }, { "year": 2015, "month": 10, "week": 44, "changes": 21 }],
    groups = { '2013': 'firstYear', '2014': 'secondYear', '2015': 'thirdYear' },
    temp = {},
    result;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    temp[a.week] = temp[a.week] || { week: a.week };
    temp[a.week][groups[a.year]] = a.changes;
});
result = Object.keys(temp).map(function (k) { return temp[k]; });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```